# Checking whether the vectors are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just finished an assignment and I would like someone that knows this material to basically check if I'm doing it right.

I was given 3 vectors <1,2,3>, <1,0,1>, <2,1,0> in R^3 and need to check if they are linearly independent. The way I did it was by creating a matrix of the following form:

1 1 2 0

2 0 1 0

3 1 0 0

I then reduced it to Echelon form and my answer resulted in 
a1 = 0, a2= 0, a3 = 0. Therefore I came to the conclusion that it is linearly independent.

---

Similarly I was given another set of vectors: <1,2>,<3,5>,<-1,3> in R^2. I used the same process as above and resulted with non trivial a1,a2,a3 therefore linearly dependent.

---

I watched a few videos online as well as read from my textbook and this is how i understood it. If you can give me some pointers or correct me if I made a mistake, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You results are correct. Note that in $\mathbb R^n$ any set of more than $n$ vectors will always be linearly dependent by reasons of dimension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532029/how-to-check-if-m-n-sized-vectors-are-linearly-independent#532046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the process you are using is correct and will give you the correct answer for any problem asking to check/verify linear independence.

Note, however, that the final column of zeros is redundant; no matter what the other vectors are, those zeros will be there through every step of row-reduction.